# java how to turn list to map of sublists if elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to learn more about the streams in java and I was wondering how can I use the toMap to change a List of items into a map that has a property of those items as key and a sublist of the same List as value. For example if I have an class:

```
public class Car {
     private String color;
     private String model;

     // getters and setters
}
```

if I have: `List<Car> carList;`, how can I get a `Map<String, List<Car>>` where the entries will be something like:

```
"BLUE" : {car1, car3, car7},
"RED" : {car2, car5, car6, car8},
"WHITE" : {car4, car9}
```

I understand that in order to get it I can run something like the following statement however I don't understand what the second parameter should be:

```
Map<String, List<Car>> carsMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getColor, ?));
```

would someone please help me get this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toMap()` normally used to collect into a `Map` that contains a single value by key.

You can use `groupingBy` for group by Color, `groupingBy` is better choice to collect into a `Map` that contains multiple values by key.

```
Map<String, List<Car>> carsMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getColor));
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds more of `groupingBy` job than a `toMap`:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getColor));
```